# Kotlin multi threaded downloading open a single file and write in different offset

Tags: java, kotlin

I am creating multi-threaded downloader in kotlin, I want to write downloaded bytes in different offsets. Current I am opening and seeking the offset on every thread. It looks like I can not open already opened file

Is there a best way to open a single file and write the bytes in different offsets?

```
launch (Dispatchers.IO) {
    val output = RandomAccessFile(file, "rw")
    output.seek(position)

    ...

    output.write(buffer, 0, bytes)
}
```

Comment: First you should make sure that you get performance increase at all. IO and network operations are much slower then CPU, so they are the real bottleneck. I doubt this is worth the effort, unless it is for educational purposes. If you are trying to optimize something, I would be glad to hear if this speeds things up significantly, please share your knowledge.

Comment: I assume asynchronous IO would make greater impact if you are up to increase performance.

Comment: Thanks, I changed my code to coroutines. Because threads make the download fast but slowing down the application.

Comment: Consider a memory mapped file.